# почему мы тут пишем int dist = 252; а на втором классе miles хотя я не могу найти между ними связи

Tags: java

```
public class Vehicle {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        opds minivan = new opds();
        opds sportscar = new opds();
        double gallons;
        int dist = 252;
// присвоить значения полям в объекте minivan
        minivan.passengers = 7;
        minivan.fuelcap = 16;
        minivan.mpg = 21;
// присвоить значения полям в объекте sportscar
        sportscar.passengers = 2;
        sportscar.fuelcap = 14;
        sportscar.mpg = 12;
        gallons = minivan.fuelneeded(dist) ;  // почему тут (dist) а не (miles) ?
        System.out.println("To go " + dist + " miles minivan needs " +
                gallons + " gallons of fuel.");
        gallons = sportscar.fuelneeded(dist);
        System.out.println("To go " + dist + " miles sportscar needs " +
                gallons + " gallons of fuel.");
    }

}




class opds {
    int passengers; // количество пассажиров
    int fuelcap;    // емкость топливного бака
    int mpg;    // потребление топлива в милях на галлон }

    введите сюда код
    double fuelneeded(int miles) {

        return (double) miles / mpg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Comment: а что надо делать:?

Comment: нажать на ссылку выделенную синим цветом в комментарии выше и прочитать :)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что переменную в одном методе решили назвать `dists`, а в другом - `miles`, их имена не обязательно должны совпадать, хотя и хранят одно и то же значение - это просто метка, по которой можно обратиться к значению.

После того, как метод `fuelneeded`  получит на вход аргумент `dists`, внутри этого метода он присвоит переданное значение `dists` своей собственной внутренней (локальной) переменной `miles` и получим результат `miles = dists`.

Теперь внутри метода значение, переданное в него, как `dists` будет известно под меткой `miles` (такое локальное именование мы указали в сигнатуре этого метода - к полученному значению обращаться по имени `miles`). Данное имя будет действительно только внутри этого метода .

Передать же в метод вы можете любое значение подходящего типа (здесь типа int): любую переменную или даже просто число:

```
fuelneeded(500);
```

внутри метода вы можете обратиться к полученному значению по имени `miles`

Вообще это основы программирования, передача значений в методы, вам бы надо почитать литературу по теории программирования вообще и на Java в частности. В данном случае о глобальных и локальных переменных, аргументах методов и областях видимости переменных.

Связь между ними такая, что дистанция (расстояние) измеряется в милях. Мы можем говорить, что машина проехала дистанцию 100 (миль) или просто машина проехала 100 миль.

Comment: спасибо я все понял, хоть кто-то меня понял и обьяснил